# Issue with responsive content, content going out of the container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I defined a viewport of:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This is the html and body style:

```
 html, body {
box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

My problem is that in some screen size the content going out of the container and doesn't fit the screen, like the following example:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQhEh.png)

full code is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/roniitzhaik/34678bq2/1/

Comment: [Check this answer from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48871380/3624336).

Comment: Try checking your jsfiddle before posting a link here...

Answer (score 0):

add

```
#branding h1 {
    ...
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    ...
}
```

or change the font-size.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an example for you to understand how it works. Examples are good for an unusually long word inside a relatively small container which won't fit.

```css
div {
   width: 100px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

/* word-wrap: break-word recently changed to overflow-wrap: break-word. */
.overflow {
  /* A long word/string will break in random places.
  A hyphen character will not be inserted. */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

/* A very long word WILL NOT start at the point it should start. 
It will be wrapped to next line and then being broken. */
.word-wrap {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

/* Avery long word starts at the point it 
should start and it is being broken. */
.word-break {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
Normal: 
<div>I am a text that 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789</div><br>

overflow-wrap: break-word; 
<div class="overflow">I am a text 000001234567890123456789</div><br>

word-wrap: break-word;
<div class="word-wrap">I am a text 000001234567890123456789</div><br>

word-break: break-all;
<div class="word-break">I am a text 000001234567890123456789</div><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

While words can long, font size should be set appropriately for the screen size. No one wants to read a letter at a time, even with **break-word** set.

Add this media query to your CSS.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) { 

  #branding h1 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

}
```